# Web-based Git that reads Markdown (i.e. README.md like Github)

Tags: git

Is there any open source package that provides a web frontend to Git that reads Markdown (i.e. README.md like Github) ?

Comment: It was an open [feature request](https://issues.gitorious.org/issues/34) but still there. However, it can be done by hacking gitorious ruby code. see this [link](http://www.8bitscraps.co.uk/blog/posts/adding-readme-to-gitorious-repository-page-like-github/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) understands Markdown syntax in most description fields and whatnot.  I don't believe that it will render Markdown content in files, though.

Note that Gitorious provides both project hosting as well as an open source server you can install on your own systems.  We're using Gitorious internally and it's quite slick.

Comment: Sure...but Gitolite isn't a web front-end like Gitorious; it's a command-line backend inspired by Gitosis.  I'm actually using Gitosis locally, and while I've looked at Gitolite I didn't feel compelled to switch.  It does have some features that, depending on your needs, may make it a more attractive solution than Gitosis.